# Trying to add a http parameter but it isn't working

Tags: java, apache, http, post

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost httpMethod = new HttpPost(this.transformURL(request));
            BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            params.setParameter("name", name);
            httpMethod.setParams(params);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            httpclient.execute(httpMethod, responseHandler);
        }catch{
           LOG.error("Error");
        } finally { 
          httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

I have the above code, and I'm trying to pass in a name variable as a paramter to get picked up in another method by `request.getParameter("name")`.

It doesn't seem to be working, when I debug I can see the parameters get set but when I follow it through to the next method that gets executed, it doesn't pick up the parameters.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

I added this and it worked great

```
 List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", request.getParameter("name")));
            httpMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check [this example](http://www.vogella.com/articles/ApacheHttpClient/article.html#example_post)? it uses the class `BasicNameValuePair` instead of `BasicHttpParams` as you do.

Also, the [documentation for the version 3.x of HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/methods/post.html) does it:

```
    PostMethod post = new PostMethod("http://jakarata.apache.org/");
    NameValuePair[] data = {
      new NameValuePair("user", "joe"),
      new NameValuePair("password", "bloggs")
    };
    post.setRequestBody(data);
    // execute method and handle any error responses.
    ...
    InputStream in = post.getResponseBodyAsStream();
    // handle response.
```

**Update**: The `BasicHttpParams` class is an implementation of the `HttpParams` interface, which as @Perception notes below, is a set of properties "that customize the behavior of the HTTP client". From the [HttpParams javadoc](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/params/HttpParams.html): *"HttpParams is expected to be used in 'write once - read many' mode. Once initialized, HTTP parameters are not expected to mutate in the course of HTTP message processing."*

Comment: Specifically, the HttpParams class is used for setting variables that customize the behavior of the HTTP client. It's not for passing information over to the server side. Thats why the OP's code is not working. I'll +1 if you expand your answer to include this info.

Comment: This got me to where I need to go. I'll update my main post with the code.